# Wpf UI bahaviour strangeness in ContinueWith, when Task itself works too fast

Tags: c#, wpf, task

Code to emulate bug.

**XAML:**

```
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0"
                Grid.Column="0"
                Margin="5,5,5,0"
                FontSize="14"
                HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                Text="User:">
    </TextBlock>
    <TextBox  Grid.Row="0"
                Grid.Column="1"
                Margin="5,5,5,0"
                Name="_txtLogin" 
                Text="{Binding Login}"/>
    <Button Grid.Row="1"
            Grid.Column="1" 
            Content="Ok"
            Width="100" 
            VerticalAlignment="Center" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
            Click="AutentificateClick" 
            Padding="0,2,0,2" 
            IsDefault="True" 
            Name="_btnOk" 
            />
</Grid>
```

**Code:**

```
private Boolean _isFirstTime = true;

public Window2()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = this;
}

private void AutentificateClick(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    _btnOk.IsEnabled = false;
    Cursor = Cursors.Wait;

    Task<Boolean>.Factory.StartNew(InitConnection).ContinueWith(t =>
    {
        if (!t.Result)
            return;

        // Emulate some work after connection's been established
        Thread.SpinWait(1000000000); (2)

        _btnOk.IsEnabled = true;
        Cursor = Cursors.Arrow;

    }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
}

private Boolean InitConnection()
{
    Thread.SpinWait(10000000); (1)
    return true;

    if (_isFirstTime)
    {
        // Emulate some work to establish connection
        Thread.SpinWait(10000000); (1)
        _isFirstTime = false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Code placed above works fine. To emulate bug comment plz these strings in `InitConnection` method:

```
Thread.SpinWait(10000000); (1)
return true;
```

and click **OK** button many times. Now you can see that `Cursor` always works fine, it changes. But button's `IsEnabled` property doesn't work very often. I mean button stays `Enabled`.

Is it one more WPF-bug or has it any rational explanation?

**.Net 4.0, Win 7**

Comment: This is because you are trying to SpinWait on main thread, your button will not get disabled it just appears pressed..

Take the task on other thread and free UI Thread this will disable the button as it should.

Or just to simplify try using commands and push this headache to Microsoft

Comment: `SpinWait` is called in both threads just to emulate some work. And exactly `SpinWait` in `Task` thread (not UI thread) makes my code proper working.

Comment: Yea I saw that in your sample.

Comment: `SpinWait` on main thread is not the problem, but you said it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext() will tell your task to execute on the UI thread.

When you call Thread.SpinWait(1000000000); the UI will become unresponsive (you will notice this if you try and do anything, such as drag the window around etc) and so the disabling of the button is not guaranteed.

So initially, I would suggest you remove TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext(), but doing so will mean that you can't re-enable the button at the end of the Task as you will no longer be on the UI thread.  If you rework your AutentificateClick method as follows, I think you will find it does what you want, and the UI will remain responsive whilst the task is executing.

```
private void AutentificateClick(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    _btnOk.IsEnabled = false;
    Cursor = Cursors.Wait;         

    Task<Boolean>.Factory.StartNew(InitConnection).ContinueWith(t =>
    {        
         if (!t.Result)
             return;

         // Emulate some work after connection's been established
         Thread.SpinWait(1000000000);

         this.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
         {
             _btnOk.IsEnabled = true;
             Cursor = Cursors.Arrow;
         }));                                
    });        
}
```

Comment: I think you don't quite understand the question or I don't understand you :).The problem is not in `ContinueWith` method. The problem is in `InitConnection` method. And `SpinWait(1)` in it is not the evil. `SpinWait(1)` makes my code works as I expect. `SpinWait(1)` resolves the bug. But It looks strange for me. Btw, `ContinueWith` only invoked in UI thred, not the `InitConnection`.

Comment: I tried your code and for me, the problem you have described occurs whether you have the calls to SpinWait in your InitConnection method or not. Did you try my suggestion? With that in place for me, the button enables and disables reliably every time.

Comment: @ Gary Wright, got you. But if there is a lot of work (for example like in my work project) in `Dispatcher.Invoke` the UI will be unresponsive as well.